# Artifactory 6.4 virtual helm repo doesn't really work?

Tags: artifactory, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to use helm repos on Artifactory (6.4) and have created **both virtual and local repo** and then uploaded (using Web UI) some example charts. Then:

Adding the virtual repo:

```
$ helm repo add helm-test-virtual http://x.x.x.x/artifactory/helm-test-virtual --username user1
Password:
"helm-test-virtual" has been added to your repositories
```

What's new in the repo:

```
$ helm repo update
Hang tight while we grab the latest from your chart repositories...
...Successfully got an update from the "helm-test-virtual" chart repository
...Successfully got an update from the "stable" chart repository
Update Complete. ⎈ Happy Helming!⎈
```

I already have some example helm charts uploaded and **reindexed**:

[image]

```
$ helm search helm-test-virtual/
No results found
```

Can anyone hint me why the `helm search helm-test-virtual/` says `No results found` ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a `helm repo update` after you've uploaded the files?
helm client has a local cache and resolves everything from it, including the search.

Comment: Yes I did run it.